# Finding differences in values with strings in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to create a new column that will describe when someone is a manager or a stand in while a manager is away.

DF

```
  ID       Name            Emp_Level          
  101      Adam               Emp 
  102      Betty              Mgr
  103      Chris(Stand in)    Mgr 
  104      Dave               Emp 
  105      Emily(Stand in)    Mgr 
  106      Frank              Mgr
```

desired output

```
  ID      Name             Emp_Level       Status
  101     Adam               Emp            Emp 
  102     Betty              Mgr            Full 
  103     Chris(Stand in)    Mgr            Partial  
  104     Dave               Mgr            Full
  105     Emily(Stand in)    Mgr            Partial
  106     Frank              Mgr            Full
```

I want to identify the differences between manager and those that are stand in managers.

I tried

```
 np.where(df['Name'].str.contains('(Stand in)', regex = True), 
 'Partical', np.where(df['Emp_Level'] == 'Mgr', 'Manager', 'Employee'))
```

Comment: _I tried ..._  If you don't show us the code that you tried, we can't point out your mistake.

Comment: Can you not just manually add a column by making a list and using pandas? It would be helpful to see your code to better understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Using a [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) might be easiest

Comment: @JohnGordon edited it with code

Comment: @SierraWalker I can but with 100s of names I would have to run through I wiyuld need to find a faster way.

Comment: @Nick map by the Type by the name?

Comment: @Coding_Nubie a map won't work now you've changed the input...

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code that you have in your question (other than it should have `regex=False`. It produces `array(['Employee', 'Manager', 'Partical', 'Employee', 'Partical', 'Manager'], dtype='<U8')` which is what you want

Comment: Why was Dave promoted to manager in your example?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do or what packages you are using but here is what I would do.

```
status=[]
for x, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Emp_level'] == "Emp":
        status.append(row['Emp_level'])
    elif row['Emp_level'] == "Mgr":
        status.append("Full")
    elif row['Emp_level'] == "Mgr(Stand in)"
        status.append("Partial")

df['status'] = status
```

This will add the column you desire by iterating through Emp_level

Although there are definitely more efficient ways to do this, depending on what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Edit: You have now moved the (stand-in) to be in the name section. My answer was written previously to this edit and I believe your original layout was easier to work with. With that edit you could use a similar tactic but you would have to check both the name and emp_level in your if statement.

Comment: Avoid using `iterrows`

Answer (score 0):

You can define the `Status` col first as `np.nan` and then use a combination of `apply()` and a function that sets the status:

```
def get_status(x):
    if x['Emp_Level'] == 'Mgr':
        if "(Stand in)" in x['Name']:
            return 'Partial'
        else:
            return "Full"
    return "Emp"


df["Status"] = np.nan
df["Status"] = df.apply(get_status, axis=1)
```

`df`:

```
    ID             Name Emp_Level   Status
0  101             Adam       Emp      Emp
1  102            Betty       Mgr     Full
2  103  Chris(Stand in)       Mgr  Partial
3  104             Dave       Emp      Emp
4  105  Emily(Stand in)       Mgr  Partial
5  106            Frank       Mgr     Full
```

Answer (score -1):

> 1. Create the dataframe:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106], 'Name':["Adam", 'Betty', 'Chris (Stand in)', "Dave", 'Emily (Stand in)', 'Frank'],'Empl_Level': ['Emp', 'Mgr', 'Mgr', 'Emp', 'Mgr', 'Mgr']})
```

> 2. Use np.where and string operation extract to find the text 'Stand in' and set the value in the new column to 'Patrical' if the first condition is True. If the condition from the first np where function is False, trigger another np.where function with condition based on the values in column, Emp_Level:

```
status_array = np.where(df.Name.str.extract(r'(Stand in)'), "Partical", np.where(df["Empl_Level"] == "Mgr", 'Full', "Emp"))
```

> 3. Convert your array to a series and concat this with your original df along axis 1 and rename your new column "Status"

```
final_df = pd.concat((df, pd.Series(status_array)), axis = 1).rename({0:'Status'}, axis = 1).copy()
```